# Can I initialize a jQuery DataTable table from HTML DOM and later control it in server-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want my table to be loaded from HTML DOM at first, but after that, I want to perform tasks like searching, pagination from server-side. How can I do that by using [DataTables](https://datatables.net)? By studying the [docs](https://datatables.net/manual/index) it seems like that I have to initialize [DataTables](https://datatables.net) with ajax, JSON and then only I can control it with server-side.

Comment: Ajax passes the paging information to your server. Its up to your server to take that information and create the data object and return it to the server.  Its done that way to prevent reposting and rebuilding the entire page from scratch (time consuming). Now there are ways to have the html generated on the first page but its not really worth the trouble to set it up that way

Comment: Why do you not want to used ajax?